# sql query to select the first occurence of a row with repeating column but unique primary key values

Tags: mysql, sql

My data has a unique primary key value for every record of the table, however other column say column 2 may have repeated values. How do i write a query such that I get the complete row only once for each column2 value?

For instance if the data is like this:

```
PID NAME
---------
1   John
2   Doe
3   John
```

The result should get the complete row, for each unique(maybe the first) occurence of the NAME so the result should be like:

```
PID NAME
---------
1   John
2   Doe
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT MIN(PID) AS PID, NAME
FROM
MYTABLE
GROUP BY NAME
ORDER BY NAME

Answer (score 0):

that would be my approach of solving this.

```
SELECT MIN(PID) 
     , NAME 
FROM TABLE 
GROUP BY NAME
```